# How can I tell compiler there is some struct not defined but will?

Tags: c++, class, struct, compiler-errors

```
#include<vector>
struct EDGE {
    VERTEX* from;
    VERTEX* to;
    int weight;
};
struct VERTEX {
    std::vector<EDGE*> edges;
};
struct MAP{
    std::vector<VERTEX> vertex;
    bool directed{ false };
}map;
```

I want to make class with these data.
How can I use undefined class but will be define?

Comment: Can you append more code of writing the class? I'm not sure what you mean by `undefined class but will be define`. Is writing the class below those structs not your case?

Comment: Forward declare it like you would a function. `struct VERTEX;`, then the definition of `EDGE`, and so on.

Comment: this is all of the codes cause compiler-error. I want to use VERTEX* in EDGE but VERTEX is not define yet, so compiler make error_issue. I use MS visual studio.

Comment: thx. I can tell it like how tell func is! thx!.@Nathan Pierson

Comment: @Lorne yeah. I got it. thx!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a technique called forward declaration. The code would look like this:

```
#include<vector>

// forward declaration of VERTEX
struct VERTEX; 

struct EDGE {
    VERTEX* from;
    VERTEX* to;
    int weight;
};

// actual definition of VERTEX
struct VERTEX {
    std::vector<EDGE*> edges;
};

struct MAP{
    std::vector<VERTEX> vertex;
    bool directed{ false };
} map;
```

But this will only work if you use pointers to the forward declared class. The compiler need to know the exact size of the member. The size of the pointer is always known, it doesn't depend on the thing it points to. So it works. But this code won't compile, because `VERTEX` is `incomplete type`, its size is unknown:

```
// forward declaration of VERTEX
struct VERTEX; 

struct EDGE {
    VERTEX from; // the VERTEX is incomplete type here
    VERTEX to;
    int weight;
};
```

Comment: Oh, I see. It depends on how much memory should compiler alloc! thx a lot. I understand why it cause error and how can I fix program about the error.